# The probability of getting 13 different cards (Ace to King) by randomly choosing from 52 cards deck?

Tags: probability

13 cards are drawn at random from a deck of 52 cards . What is the probability that all cards I've got are different cards, Ace to King with whatever pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Probability of drawing 13 different cards $= \dfrac{[{4 \choose 1}]^{13}}{{{52} \choose {13}}}$

One can calculate the rest

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** How can you relate what you want with

$$\mathcal P(\text{first card is ace})\cdot \mathcal P(\text{second card is a 2})\cdots \mathcal P(\text{thirteenth card is a king}) $$

Hint for the hint: they are *not* the same.

Comment: It's like that I guess: 4/52 x 4/51 x 4/50 x 4/49 x 4/48 x 4/47 x 4/46 x 4/45 x 4/44 x 4/43 x 4/42 x 4/41 x 4/40 =  ,,,,  is it right?

Comment: @NyoHtetNyo Yes, that is the probability I wrote. But is that your final answer? Is that the probability you asked for?

Comment: yes, that's what I asked for. What happened to me is that me and other three friends are playing poker. It's a kind of poker which is similar to texas poker. We use only one deck and all of us receive 13 cards each randomly. Then we split the cards into three groups: 1st group - 3 cards 2nd group - 5 cards and 3rd group - 5 as well. The only discipline is that the power of 2nd group must be higher than 1st and that of 3rd group must be higher than 2nd. Then, all 1st group of each of us compared according to the rule of Texas, who is higher. Then 2nd group followed and then 3rd.

Comment: If the person get 3 colours (that's what we used to call), it means the first group 3 cards in same pattern: 2nd group 5 cards in same pattern and 3rd group 5 cards in same pattern (not necessarily all 13 has only one pattern which will be extremely unlikely to happen), this person automatically win with no need to comparing groups with others, winning 3 times of bet (we bet 1 unit for each group). Then suddenly, I got 13 different cards. We know it's more difficult than 3 colors and I automatically win but we can't figure out how many times of bet I should win. It's happened 20 years ago.

Comment: @NyoHtetNyo what I meant is that is not your final answer. The result you wrote is for drawing the 13 cards in that specific order. You don't care about the order in which they are drawn, thus you have to multiply by $13! $... Do you get why?